# Why my feet bones don't want to be moved in object mode?

Tags: object-mode

In pose mode the feet can be moved normally.

But in object mode, the foot bones stuck.

There's a constraint - child of, in the foot bone. All xyz location and scale tranforms is disabled. Only the rotation is enabled. If I disable the constraint, the foot bones can be moved in object mode. But I need that constraint. And why does it behave like that in object mode?

Is this a bug, why it has to act differently in pose mode and object mode?

[image]

[image]

Below I have a file with two bones only. I cut all the bones and meshes from the same file to simplify. But the bones still behave the same.

After testing and testing, It seems that this behavior happens every time I made a keyframe. If there were not keyframe, I can move the foot along with the other bones in the object mode.

Is this actually normal?